# Why are my submenus being covered?

Tags: css

What in my CSS is covering up the sub-menus for my drop down menu? Here is my template. Hovering over "Bar" is supposed to produce a sub-menu.

http://dl.dropbox.com/u/1531353/Misc/menuBarCovered/index.html

I tried altering the z-index of the submenus to no avail.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No need to use overflow:hidden on every element.

If you remove this property from the header css declaration you'll be able to see the submenu on hover.

By using overflow:hidden, you are clipping and making invisible anything that falls below the boundaries of your element.

Answer (score 1):

agreeing with @Pablo - quick fix - remove overflow:hidden from header.